# How to Filter Object out of nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to filter the hole Object (objB) out of an Array, which is matching a Value (titleB2) of a Property.

```
const array = [
  {
    name: 'objA',
    subArray: []
  }, {
    name: 'objB',
    subArray: [
      {
        title: 'titleB'
      }, {
        title: 'titleB2'
      }, {
        title: 'titleB3'
      }
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'objC',
    subArray: [
      {
        title: 'titleC'
      }, {
        title: 'titleC2'
      }, {
        title: 'titleC3'
      }
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'objD',
    subArray: []
  }
]

const filterArray = array.filter(a => a.subArray.length > 0);
console.log(filterArray);
// Output: objB + objC

const resArray = filterArray.filter(a => a.subArray.filter(f => f.title === 'titleB2'));
console.log(resArray);
// Output: objB + objC
```

I guess, I do something logically wrong. But what exactly?

I need the output

```
{
  name: 'objB',
  subArray: [
    {
      title: 'titleB'
    }, {
      title: 'titleB2'
    }, {
      title: 'titleB3'
    }
  ]
}
```

I can imagine I use the filter `filterArray.filter()` wrong, because it already filtered? But I do this because I have multiple arrays in one array. Well, I am not realy sure, to be honest.

But what I dont understand is, why can I use the condition `a => a.subArray.length > 0?` but not `f => f.title === 'titleB2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `some()` instead of `filter()` on subarray. It returns a boolean.

```js
const resArray = array.filter(a => a.subArray.some(f => f.title === 'titleB2'));
console.log(resArray);
// Output: objB + objC
```

```html
<script>

const array = [
  {
    name: 'objA',
    subArray: []
  }, {
    name: 'objB',
    subArray: [
      {
        title: 'titleB'
      }, {
        title: 'titleB2'
      }, {
        title: 'titleB3'
      }
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'objC',
    subArray: [
      {
        title: 'titleC'
      }, {
        title: 'titleC2'
      }, {
        title: 'titleC3'
      }
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'objD',
    subArray: []
  }
]
</script>
```

Comment: wow, ok thanks that clears the thing out for me. Thank you very  much! :D

Answer (score 1):

To find objects with a particular title in the subarray you can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on the subarray, which will return true if one of the items in the subarray matches your condition (in this case the title):

```js
const array = [{name: 'objA',subArray: []}, {name: 'objB',subArray: [{title: 'titleB'}, {title: 'titleB2'}, {title: 'titleB3'}]}, {name: 'objC',subArray: [{title: 'titleC'}, {title: 'titleC2'}, {title: 'titleC3'}]}, {name: 'objD',subArray: []}]

let found = array.filter(item => item.subArray.some(sub => sub.title === 'titleB2'))
console.log(found)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This really helped me

Comment: No need to thank people @equaliser — that's what upvotes and selecting the correct answer are for.

Comment: I know, but I mustnt: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Thats why i mention that, so you know that I am really thankful :)